# Why have I been accused of 'manupulative twisting'?

Tags: discussion

Spiacent for asking this question, but in a comment posted under an answer to 'Can theology be defined "the science of faith" nowadays?' a user accused me of 'manipulative twisting':

> The author said nothing about faith. He said
>   'things divine'. The two cannot be assumed to be the same. The question twisted what Hooker said and you in your answer gave credibility to this **manipulative twisting** instead of exposing it. Poor show. –  gideon marx

Since I'm not an expert, I feel of having manipulated nothing.

Thus, I would like to know what the difference between 'things divine' and 'faith' is and how, if any, the difference would have influenced the question.

Peace be with you, and thank you all.

Comment: If people are taking what you say wrong, it just means you're participating on the site.  I sometimes feel like I can't say "my name is David" without offending someone these days.  (To be fair, I have rubbed plenty the wrong way, but still...)  That said, it might be better to ask gideon in chat what he meant by it, rather than an open ended question for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't make anything of it. Just a misunderstanding. The commenter is welcome to make his own post as well and can address the "issue" if he wants. As the answer that received the comment, I already agreed to address the commenter's concern, though I personally think it is a small distinction.